# Position checkboxes vertical each other other in Agular material

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have some checkboxes, but they are positioned next each other and not under each other.

I have this:

```
.mat-header-cell mat-checkbox {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: -10px;
  display: block;
}

.mat-header-cell:hover mat-checkbox {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: -10px;
  display: block;
}
.mat-checkbox-inner-container{
  display: block;
}
```

And this is the html:

```
  <div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let item of returnProjectCodes; let i = index">
            <mat-checkbox

              (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
              (change)="selected = i"
              [checked]="selelected === i"

            >{{item.name}}
          </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
```

But the header 'projects' doesnt positioned correct anymore.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="projects">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (mouseover)="show = true" (mouseout)="show = false" mat-sort-header i18n>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of returnProjectCodes; let i = index">
              <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="selected = i" [checked]="selelected === i"
                >{{ item.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
          Projects
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.projects }}</td>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: Your dive structure should be like this : `<div class="col"> <div class="row" *ngFor=..`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure entirely what you are asking, but I assume it is for them to be in vertical order and not horizontal.

You can apply a CSS display as block as you are doing, however you should do it on the parent, and the col-sm-12 is probably keeping the width small so that they line up horizontally.

You can remove that and try setting the width to 100% (this probably wont be necessary, it should default to that width for a block div)

Please keep in mind the more context you can provide the better, such as a picture of what you have versus what you are going for.

Comment: Yes, I want them vertical and not horizontal. Because they are now horizontal and not vertical